# How to solve the error "Webdriver cannot be resolved to a type"?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

[image]

To clear and run my code.

> Webdriver cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Libraries_ a JAR is missing containing the `ChromeDriver` class. When coding in Java and not in Python, better switch to the Java perspective (via the buttons in the upper right).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, or other text. And in case you need to post a picture, definitely do not take pictures of your monitor with a camera, learn how to take proper screenshot

Comment: @JamesZ I see a poor quality photograph of a screen showing the Eclipse Java IDE 2022-03 with the PyDev plugin installed and with an opened Java editor showing also some code, but which is not relevant here. I don't see a picture of code here. Please say exactly what you need to help, rather than telling people who ask for help what not to do. Be aware that there are workplaces where taking screenshots is blocked and people work around this by using their mobile phones.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
 ... 15 more        this error is showing but i did not use maven. why slf4j error is showing here. kindly help me to resolve !

Answer (score 0):

Please check and cross-verify the following to resolve the issue.

1: You might have unknowingly removed webdriver jars, try adding the webdriver(ChromeDriver) and selenium jars again.
2: Try using MAVEN and make sure while editing pom.xml you have provided the accurate scope and version of dependencies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: without maven can't run selenium code? how to clear slf4j error ?

Comment: Maven is useful to add versions and dependencies with ease. But based on the above code instead of using driver.navigate.to try using driver.get(”url”).
The error you mentioned above can be resolved by declaring the slf4j in your Maven ‭pom.xml‬ file. If not using maven, download the library and add it in the classpath.